# glfw not working in sublime text in linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw, glew

when i run the code it says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[Finished in 1.5s with exit code 139]
```

i do not know what to do but i remove it runs well without crashing

```
unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,6* sizeof(float), posotions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

[image: code1]

[image: code2]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include code in your post in the future. (instead of a picture/screenshot)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You didn't initialize GLEW. It can be done with `glewInit();`

GLEW is the library that *gives* you those OpenGL functions.